# How to structure a library in ES6 that has to be consumed by ES5 code?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

If I have a JavaScript library/plugin developed in ES6, a consumer of our library is able to import & consume the library using ES6 modules:

```
import MyLibrary from 'mylibrary';

let myLibrary = new MyLibrary();
myLibrary.doStuff()
```

And this works very well, as our module is bundled neatly and is not dependent on the client's implementations, and could also be made available over **npm**. It is then the responsibility of the consumer to run `browserify` and `babel` to make this code usable in the browser (if necessary).

However some of our consumers do not use ES6 and do not want to include transpiling as part of their build process.

What is the best way to structure my ES6 code to make it usable by an ES5 consumer? In this case the consumer is hoping for something like:

```
var myLibrary = myLibrary.create();
myLibrary.doStuff();
```

Comment: "It is then the responsibility of the consumer to run `browserify` and `babel` to make this code usable in the browser". Why don't you transpile it yourself and deploy it in ES5?

Comment: He would still need to use `require('myLibrary')` to load the library, another way would be that you build an index in your library that references everything necessary and transpilesl down to es5 but I would say that is your choice if the consumer should do that or you

Comment: Deliver ES6 module through `src/` directory, transpile and save ES5 version in `lib/` directory, deliver both, let people choose what they prefer. You can automate transpilation from ES6 to ES5 easily.

Comment: `In this case the consumer is hoping for something like` what's the point here? not using the `new` keyword, or the omitting the import?

Comment: @Thomas omitting the import.

Comment: @mjh that is similar to what I am trying to do. At the moment I am transpiling to ES5 using `browserify`, but I am unsure if it is possible to use the module without forcing the consumer to use CommonJS. Ultimately I do not want to dictate to the consumers (assuming there are numerous) what bundling tools or module loaders they are forced to use.

Comment: I am looking for something similar to http://www.richardrodger.com/2013/09/27/how-to-make-simple-node-js-modules-work-in-the-browser/#.WTl5tXV97MU however I have been unable to get this to work with ES6 modules.